# SDL Web 8 Community Posts?

Tags: discussion, web8

With the release of SDL Web 8, do you have posts you'd like to share with the community?

I'm coming across a few posts as you explore the new version and think it'd be helpful to aggregate a reading list here.

Answer (score 6):

Currently I've done:

- http://www.blog.electricbiro.co.uk/2015/12/04/sdl-web-8-wtf-is-topology-manager/
- http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/sdl-web-8-setting-up-publishing

Answer (score 4):

SDL Webinars:

- [Launch](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/22/sdl-web-8-launch-webcast-recording)
- [Technical Deep Dive](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/w/wiki/818.sdl-web-8-technical-deep-dive)

SDL Blog Posts:

- [SDL Web 8: What's in a Name?](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/09/18/sdl-web-8-what-s-in-a-name-part-1)
- [SDL Web 8: Roadmap and Features](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/09/25/sdl-web-8-roadmap-and-features-part-2-of-5)
- [SDL Web 8: UI Quick Preview](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/10/05/sdl-web-8-user-interface-quick-preview-part-3-of-5)

[Topology Manager Demo](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/w/web8-training/900.sdl-web-8-topology-manager-demo) (video)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very cool post by our own Renze de Vries on how to get SDL Web 8 working with Docker-Compose and SpringBoot - for the cloud hipsters out there.

https://renzedevries.wordpress.com/2015/12/23/continuous-deployment-with-docker-compose-and-spring-boot/

Answer (score 3):

Below are couple of my blog posts:

[SDL Web 8 Prerequisite Cheatsheet](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2015/12/21/sdl-web-8-prerequisite-cheatsheet/)

[SDL Web 8 - Five Notable Changes](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2015/12/28/sdl-web-8-five-notable-changes/)